# Sometimes, when working with Liferay Portal 6.1.1 I get an error page with next content

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portal, jsr286

Sometimes, when working with Liferay Portal 6.1.1 I get an error page with next content

can someone explain, how to resolve this problem?

Content:

```
The page cannot be displayed
Explanation: The Web server refused the connection, possibly because a service on the upstream server is inactive.

Try the following:

    Refresh page: Search for the page again by clicking the Refresh button. The timeout may have occurred due to Internet congestion.
    Check spelling: Check that you typed the Web page address correctly. The address may have been mistyped.
    Access from a link: If there is a link to the page you are looking for, try accessing the page from that link.
    Contact website: You may want to contact the website administrator to make sure the Web page still exists. You can do this by using the e-mail address or phone number listed on the website home page. 

Technical Information (for support personnel)

    Error Code 10061: Connection refused
    Background: When the gateway or proxy server contacted the upstream (Web) server, the connection was refused. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the upstream server.
```

Before I add to the configuration proxy setting for firewall, I thought that it was problem, but it didn't help.

And sometimes portal show another error page, maybe they have dependence, another
[error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977611/getting-blank-page-with-next-content-in-liferay)

Comment: Could you perhaps describe some more background information about when you get this exception? 
Could you also describe your setup? Is there a proxy or web server in front of your liferay instance?

Comment: This is an error that your firewall/proxy displays because, for some reason, it can't forward the request as expected. Try to reproduce without that firewall to identify an underlying Liferay problem - otherwise it's probably that firewall/proxy.

Comment: I have tested it on server side, i.e. look throgh ie on server machine, like localhost, and there is no problems